# Java:ResultSet error

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc

```
    String temp[]=bookName.split(" ");
    ArrayList list=new ArrayList();

    try {
        con=ds.getConnection(); 
        pst=con.prepareStatement("select distinct book_name from booksinventory");
        rs=pst.executeQuery();

        for(int i=0;i<temp.length;i++)
        {
            while(rs.next())
            {
                //System.out.println(rs.getString(1)+" contains "+temp[i]);
                line no 631 --> System.out.println(rs.getString(1)+" contains "+temp[i]+":"+(rs.getString(1).toUpperCase()).contains(temp[i].toUpperCase()));
                if((rs.getString(1).toUpperCase()).contains(temp[i].toUpperCase()))
                {
                    list.add(rs.getString(1));
                    System.out.println(list);
                }
            }
            rs.beforeFirst();
        }
        System.out.println(list);
        Set<String> set=new HashSet<String>();
        set.addAll(list);
        list.removeAll(list);
        list.addAll(set);
        list.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));

        con.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return list;
```

Here I'm trying to search through my records to check whether a particular set of keywords are present in the record. I tried almost everything cant figure out the error.. I think its with the statement "rs.beforeFirst()" because it is only printing for the first iteration.. Following is from the console..

```
    16:55:06,240 INFO  [STDOUT] Let us C contains let:true
    16:55:06,240 INFO  [STDOUT] [Let us C]
    16:55:06,240 INFO  [STDOUT] Let us C++ contains let:true
    16:55:06,240 INFO  [STDOUT] [Let us C, Let us C++]
    16:55:06,240 INFO  [STDOUT] Let us HTML contains let:true
    16:55:06,240 INFO  [STDOUT] [Let us C, Let us C++, Let us HTML]
    16:55:06,240 INFO  [STDOUT] dfgdfg contains let:false
    16:55:06,240 INFO  [STDOUT] digital electronics contains let:false
    16:55:06,240 INFO  [STDOUT] java contains let:false
    16:55:06,241 INFO  [STDOUT] oops contains let:false
    16:55:06,241 INFO  [STDOUT] quantum computing contains let:false
    16:55:06,241 INFO  [STDOUT] sdf contains let:false
    16:55:06,241 ERROR [[SearchBooksCombo]] Servlet.service() for servlet SearchBooksCombo threw exception
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.classes.dao.LibraryDAO.getMatchingBooks(LibraryDAO.java:631)
        at com.classes.servlets.SearchBooksCombo.doGet(SearchBooksCombo.java:37)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:654)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:557)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:481)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:968)
        at org.apache.jsp.addCopy_jsp._jspService(addCopy_jsp.java:80)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:373)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:336)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    16:55:06,241 ERROR [[jsp]] Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.classes.dao.LibraryDAO.getMatchingBooks(LibraryDAO.java:631)
        at com.classes.servlets.SearchBooksCombo.doGet(SearchBooksCombo.java:37)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:654)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:557)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:481)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:968)
        at org.apache.jsp.addCopy_jsp._jspService(addCopy_jsp.java:80)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:373)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:336)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    16:55:06,242 INFO  [CachedConnectionManager] Closing a connection for you.  Please close them yourself: org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.jdk5.WrappedConnectionJDK5@52fdeb
    java.lang.Throwable: STACKTRACE
        at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionManager.registerConnection(CachedConnectionManager.java:290)
        at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:423)
        at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2$ConnectionManagerProxy.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:849)
        at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:89)
        at com.classes.dao.LibraryDAO.getMatchingBooks(LibraryDAO.java:622)
        at com.classes.servlets.SearchBooksCombo.doGet(SearchBooksCombo.java:37)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:654)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:557)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:481)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:968)
        at org.apache.jsp.addCopy_jsp._jspService(addCopy_jsp.java:80)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:373)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:336)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Which line in the code is 631?

Comment: LibraryDAO...check whether its object is created or not.

Comment: Its working fine for the first iteration.. In my db I have books like Let us C,Let us C++ etc.. (I don't refer them :D) .. When bookName contains "let us".. it stores all books with "let" in their name(as seen in the console).. but does not proceed to the second for iteration.. what could be the problem ?

Comment: @Shoaib Chikate: `LibraryDAO` can't be `null` by itself, because there is a `NPE` **in** this class at the method `getMatchingBooks`. But anyway, the line number could be of interest...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"because it is only printing for the first iteration."*

From the [`ResultSet` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html?is-external=true).

> A default `ResultSet` object is not updatable and **has a cursor that moves forward only. Thus, you can iterate through it only once and only from the first row to the last row**. It is possible to produce ResultSet objects that are scrollable and/or updatable. The following code fragment, in which `con` is a valid `Connection` object, illustrates how to make a result set that is scrollable and insensitive to updates by others, and that is updatable. See ResultSet fields for other options.

```
   Statement stmt = con.createStatement(
                                  ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                                  ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
   ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT a, b FROM TABLE2");
   // rs will be scrollable, will not show changes made by others,
   // and will be updatable
```

Comment: Oops ! How can I forget that ! Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would write that class, based on what you've posted:

```
package persistence;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * BookDao description here
 * @author Michael
 * @link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21380043/javaresultset-error#21380043
 * @since 1/27/14 6:51 AM
 */
public class BookDao {


    public static final String SELECT_BOOK_NAMES = "select distinct book_name from booksinventory";
    private Connection con;

    public BookDao(Connection con) {
        this.con = con;
    }

    public List<String> getAllBookNamesByKeywords() throws SQLException {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            ps = con.prepareStatement(SELECT_BOOK_NAMES);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()) {
                list.add(rs.getString(1));
            }
        } finally {
            DatabaseUtils.close(rs);
            DatabaseUtils.close(ps);
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

You do a lot of things that are either unnecessary or incorrect.

Comment: You're missing the consideration of which books will be added to the list because of the search criteria (`temp`). Apart from that it is in fact much more cleaner!

Comment: This won't scale as the number of book names gets larger.  A better solution would let the database handle what it's good at.  I think a better query, perhaps an indexer, would be far more scalable.